# Removing /user from a devise url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want users to be able to sign in using the url http://myapp.com/sign_in, so I added the following to my routes.

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

This works, but the new_user_session_path provided by devise still points at http://myapp.com/users/sign_in.

How can I change it to http://myapp.com/sign_in please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redefine that path helper in your route definition:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
end
```

This is what I do all the time and it works fine.

Note that I also removed the `:to` part in your route. You can use directly the `=>` to map the URL to the controller's action. But I don't think it's related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a forward slash to `sign_in`:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

Comment: that doesn't change the path for new_user_session_path

Answer (score 0):

in your routes.rb file (outside of `devise_scope :user` block) add:

```
match "/sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
```